# Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a api controller in my mvc application and I tried to post data to the api, but I am getting the problem of  **Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API .** Here is my error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.44:100/api/name. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53114' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

I have installed **Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2**

my api code

```
namespace Restaurant.Controllers{
[EnableCors(origins: "http://192.168.0.44:100", headers: "*", methods: "get,post")]

    public class OrderController : ApiController  
    {
        public Test Post( string name,int age)  
        {
            Test test = new Test()
            {
               Name=name,
               Age=age
            };
            db.test.Add(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return test;
        }}
```

WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });         
    config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());                       
}
```

View

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
 function add() {      
        var DatatTest = {
        name: $("#txtname").val(),
        age: $("#txtage").val()
    };
    $.ajax({            
        url: 'http://192.168.0.44:100/api/name',
        type: 'Post',
        data: JSON.stringify(DatatTest),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok");},
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert("error");}
    });
}
</script>
```

web.config

```
httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>               
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now I am getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.44:100/api/Order. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53114' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps.

In web.config

```
config.EnableCors();
```

In your controller add this

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Note: origins should be the client address, and not the sever address ,and make sure you do not add a black slash at the end of origins URL.

Comment: I hope  i have done that .can i use IP for origins  ?

Answer (score 3):

It is the Error that shows while calling web API. there are two reasons behind it.

1. CORS
2. Headers

we can enable the CORS in webapiconfig.cs file

```
CONFIG.EnableCors(cors);
```

to resolve headers we should allow WEBAPI to allow all the Headers as below

```
 EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
```

[Reference Article](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2017/08/web-api-throws-no-access-control-allow.html)